# Android remove PopupWindow background

Tags: android

I use PopupWindow class for creating custom popup window.

But when I add layout_margin (in my example 15dp) on main there is transparent gray background.

How to remove transparent background?

Please see picture

[image]

EDIT
here is my code

```
    window = new PopupWindow(customTool.getContext());
    window.setWidth(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
    window.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    window.setTouchable(true);
    window.setFocusable(true);
    window.setOutsideTouchable(true);
    window.setAnimationStyle(R.style.Animations_PopDownMenu_Left);
window.setContentView(customTool);
    window.showAtLocation(customTool, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 0, 100);
```

Comment: Did you called setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) method on  popupWindow object ?

Comment: no I don't use setBackgroundDrawable , I will edit question with my code

Comment: Yeah, you need to call setBackgroundDrawable method either by null or pass BitmapDrawable object.

Comment: In xml I use android:background="#0ff000", and this work fine

Comment: Cool, FYI: android:background , setBackgroundResource and setBackgroundDrawable all do same thing. If you want to look how it is implemented here is a [link](http://www.google.com/codesearch#oOy_5JrVRNM/trunk/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/View.java&ct=rc&cd=10&q=setBackgroundResource) search for setBackgroundResource

Answer (score 9, accepted):

hmm - try setting on your popup dialog try 
yourDiag.setBackgroundDrawable(null);

Comment: when I use `setBackgroundDrawable(null);` transparent background is gone, but setOutsideTouchable not work. I implement `setTouchInterceptor` but when I set `setBackgroundDrawable(null);` not work. Suggestion?

Comment: instead `setBackgroundDrawable(null);` I use `new BitmapDrawable()`

Comment: Jovan is right. This looks like a bug in PopupWindow - setting the background drawable to null kills the OnTouchListener but using a new, empty BitmapDrawable() does the trick.

Comment: or alternatively instead of `setBackgroundDrawable(null)` use `popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ctx.getResources.getColor(android.R.color.transparent))
)`